# Change Checkbox id in Repeater

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

i have repeater to retrieve image from data base and i need check box for any image to select and delete from database , how can i get the check box id to tell my button event to delete image from database ?

i need check box id to tell my query delete which image .

my repeater :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterPersonnel" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <td>  <img src="../Handler/GalleryPhoto.ashx?id=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.PhotoId")%>&size=178" alt="" class="img-border" /> 
        <input type="checkbox" id= '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.PhotoId") %>'/>
      </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Or is there any way to delete my image with java script ?

Comment: on asp button on click you can find checked checkboxes inside repeater control using findcontrol , have you tried that ?

Comment: SaB, your question title is "Change Checkbox id in Repeater" but your question actually appears to be about how to delete the image using JavaScript. You should update your title to accurately reflect the question so you don't have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @mason , my answer reflect the same

Comment: @vishalsharm No, you're manipulating Hidden Fields and your answer assumes a postback.

Comment: @mason  No i want java script as my plane B !! but i prefer use other solution .

Comment: @vishalsharma thank you for tracking , i found some solution to use java script but its Not my favorite .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
<tr><th>Id</th><th>Image</th><th>Delete?</th></tr> 
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterPersonnel" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <tr class="PersonnelRow" data-photoid='<%# (Container.DataItem as WebApplication1.PhotoInfo).PhotoId %>'>
           <td>
               <%# (Container.DataItem as WebApplication1.PhotoInfo).PhotoId %>
           </td>
           <td>
               <img src="../Handler/GalleryPhoto.ashx?id=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.PhotoId")%>&size=178" alt="" class="img-border" />
           </td>
           <td> 
               <input type="checkbox" data-photoid='<%# (Container.DataItem as WebApplication1.PhotoInfo).PhotoId %>' class="DeletionCheckbox" />
           </td>
       </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="ApplyChanges()">Apply Changes</button>
```

Notice I made a few changes. I moved all of your elements into separate td's, and each repeated item now gets its own tr. I also added a td for showing the photo ID, and sprinkled in the strongly typed photo id using `data-` attributes. Since it's now strongly typed and not relying on `DataBinder.Eval()`, if you change any of the property names they'll automatically be updated. Less chance of something breaking at runtime. So far, this should all be fairly straight forward. I've also added a button that will call this `ApplyChanges()` Javascript. Let's look at that...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ApplyChanges() {
        $(".DeletionCheckbox:Checked").each(function (index, element) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "api/Photos/Delete?photoid=" + $(element).data("photoid"),
                type: "DELETE"
            })
            .done(function () {
                $(".PersonnelRow[data-photoid='" + $(element).data("photoid") + "']").remove();
            })
            .fail(function () {
                alert("Failure deleting photo: " + $(element).data("photoid"));
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

So first the script gets all the elements with a class of `DeletionCheckbox` (but only if they're checked). It iterates through those elements using the jQuery `.each()` function. We then use jQuery AJAX to call out to a Web API (which I'll get to in a moment), and we pass the photoid via query string. When the AJAX call is successful, we then get the element with the class of `PersonnelRow` where the `data-photoid` matches the photoid of the deleted element, and we remove that row (and all it's sub elements) from the DOM so it will no longer display. I did it by calling remove, but a snazzy way to do it would be to fade it out, then remove it. And if the AJAX call fails, we display an alert message.

Side note, I'm using the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/) in my JavaScript. If you're not familiar with it, it makes JavaScript a lot simpler. We can do what I've done with "plain" JavaScript, but we'd need a lot more code and it'd be harder to read. There are other frameworks out there that would also make them easy, but jQuery is one of the most popular. It's also "blessed" by Microsoft and included in all their default templates. If you've never used it before, you can add it to your site by placing this script tag *before* the JavaScript that needs it. `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Now the only remaining puzzle piece is how do we process that AJAX request on the server? You'll need to add the [Web API library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/) to your application. Then you'll need to configure the routing (I won't go into detail here, but that's [covered on Microsoft's site](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api).) Then you'd create a new Web API controller class in your application, using the following code:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Photos")]
public class PhotosController : ApiController
    {
    [Route("Delete")]
    public void Delete(string photoid)
        {
        //code to delete photo from database
        }
    }
```

I assume you know how to perform an SQL delete command to drop the photo from your database, so I leave that implementation detail to you. Notice that I used [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) so that we can easily know the URL we should specify in our JavaScript AJAX call.

So this seems like a lot (but really, it's fairly easy concepts), but it has a number of advantages over the other solutions here. Most of the other answers (except Lajos') require a postback to the server. That will post your entire form to the server, run through the page lifecycle, and then require that the server send the entire contents for the page back to the client. That's a *lot* of stuff just to delete a photo or two. That is very slow for the client, since it requires a lot of data to be sent and received from the server. It's also bad for the server, because it has to do a lot of extra processing to handle building up the page. The user will also see the page refresh, which can be disorienting.

My method (and Lajos') makes a very small HTTP delete request to the server, and basically the only thing it's passing in are the the HTTP headers (which contain the photoid in the URL). That's going to be very small, just a few kilobytes. The server doesn't have to do the page life cycle. It simply handles the delete command, and replies with a very small HTTP response that has a status code of `200 OK`. Very little bandwidth used, very little server processing time/memory consumed. And the user won't have the page refresh, they'll just see the checked rows disappear (jQuery has a [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) method if you want to make it look even nicer).

Comment: Thank you for complete explain .
i have another problem with java script , i use script to create table row in asp panel , but when i try to hide and visible panel , my row data is gone ; is there any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: @SaB That sounds like a separate issue. You should create a new question, make sure to include relevant code.

Comment: i ask the question how to generate table row with java script and someone help me , but i Bring up my problem and nobody answer me . 
Is it necessary to create a new topic ?

Comment: @SaB Yes, you should only have one question per topic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27362899/create-row-with-java-script-but-its-gone-on-my-asp-panel

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `data-id` attribute to your `checkbox` containing the actual `id` of the photo:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-id= '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.PhotoId") %>'/>
```

and in your javascript:

```
function collectPhotos(context) {
    var photos = [];
    context.each(function() {
        photos[photos.length] = $(this).data("id");
    });
    return photos;
}
```

where `context` is a selector for your checkboxes and at the end you will get an array containing the IDs.

You post this array to the server and you should call a method, which should execute a `delete` which has a filter like

```
where id in (<your comma separated list>)
```

Naturally, beware sql injections.

EDIT:
As for Mason's suggestion, I add some additional information which might help:

1. How to remove an item from the DOM:

   `$(yourSelector).remove();`
2. Display a message:

   `alert("Checkboxes were removed");`
3. Post the array to the server using AJAX:

   ```
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: yourPage,
       data: {photoIDs: collectPhotos($("#" + parentID + " checkbox"))},
       success: function(response) {
           $(yourSelector).remove();
           alert("Checkboxes were removed");
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: One final step you might include is removing the image from the DOM and/or displaying a "successful deletion" confirmation message. You might also mention how to post the array to the server, such as using AJAX combined with Web API.

Comment: @mason im not  familiar with Ajax to much.

Comment: @SaB Time to learn, as you'll have a faster, more efficient, and easier to maintain site.

Comment: @mason can you offer me some document ?

Comment: Edited my answer with some details.

Answer (score -2):

because you want the solution in javascript

add any class for e.g. chkbox in your checkbox element and then on your save button's click

find the checked boxes using following javascript

```
document.querySelectorAll('.chkbox:checked')
```

you can then iterate through checkboxes , get and set values in hiddenfields somewhere and then can get on server side