# Create row with java script but its gone on my asp panel

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have asp panel to show some register form detail for user to complete the form  , when i generate row with my script , its gone when i try to hide my panel , i mean when table row generated , and user fill the textbox when click the next button , the current panel set visible to false and new panel visible set true and my generated table row is gone .

My scripts

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var row = table.insertRow();

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        cell3.appendChild(element2);

        var cell4 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element3 = document.createElement("input");
        cell4.appendChild(element3);

        var cell5 = row.insertCell(3);
        var element4 = document.createElement("input");
        cell5.appendChild(element4);

        var cell6 = row.insertCell(4);
        var element5 = document.createElement("input");
        cell6.appendChild(element5);
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

My asp panel :

```
    <asp:Panel ID="PanelProfile" runat="server">
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
<table id="dataTable">
    <caption>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
    </caption>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFam_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFam_relation" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFam_age" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFam_education" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFam_statuse" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
<asp:Button ID="ButtonNext" runat="server" Text="Next Panel" />
</table>
</asp:Panel>
```

Edit : Nobody can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises because you've misunderstood the ASP.NET life cycle. When you have a postback to the server (for example, after clicking ButtonNext), any client side changes that you've made will disappear, and the page is regenerated from the server and sent to the client.

There's several ways to get around this:

1. You can use server side code to add new rows. This is the least efficient but easiest method.
2. You can detect on the server by reading the posted form values how many rows were added and what their values were, then recreate them on the server and send them back as part of the response.
3. You can eliminate postbacks and use client side JavaScript to do showing/hiding of the panel. I like this style best because it's the most efficient use of resources, and you don't have both client and server side trying to manipulate the DOM.